# How to get file attachment detail from Chrome Webrequest

Tags: google-chrome, https, google-chrome-extension

I am writing chrome extension in which I am reading POST data using [chrome.WebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) APIs.
I am able to read mail contents but not able to read attachment details, neither file name nor attached file contents. Does anybody have any idea how to get attachment detail using chrome.WebRequest.

Note : I am registering my extension for onBeforeRequest event.

Answer (score 0):

In the `details` parameter of the event listener, there's a property called `requestBody`, *which is currently experimental*. POST data can be read from it. Note that you have to specify `'requestBody'` in the `extraInfoSpec` parameter when registering the event listener.

Comment: I have specified 'requestBody' in the extraInfoSpec parameter, and I am able to read all values including 'mail body', 'subject', 'sender', 'receipent' but in the attachment field instead of showing actual file name it is showing some encrypted string by which I can't make out which file it is referring to or is there any way I can get the data of attached file like it comes in Http request in the form of MIME.